# How can I get the CPU temperature from the command line on Apple Silicon M1

Tags: terminal, command-line, hardware, temperature, apple-silicon

I wanted to monitor handy temperature data like I did dozen times on Linux machines. No problem! I found a beautiful one-liner:

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers smc | grep -i "CPU die temperature"
```

and immediately have got the error `powermetrics: unrecognized sampler: smc`

Then I tried a dozen of other suggestions, but none of them work well with Apple Silicon.

It's a very strange decision for me to get rid of those sensors; definitely a classic Apple-way. Also iStats, TG Pro, and other GUI tools work perfectly fine, so something there definitely exists.

Also, I wanted to add temperature sensors in `htop`, but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Which dozen have you tried, so people don't recommend them again? Also, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x?rq=1 lists some more.

Comment: try this https://github.com/barelyhuman/temp-cli

Answer (score 14):

Temperature is not mapped to the power metrics command line app on Apple Silicon. What is easy to see **thermal pressure** which aggregates temperature across the 15 to 42 cores present on M1 integrated package SIP/SOC.

```
sudo powermetrics -s thermal
```

You can also monitor CPU / GPU frequency if you need to know relative activity levels.

```
sudo powermetrics -s cpu_power,gpu_power
```

Comment: suspicious..., why would Apple do that.... maybe because their M2 MacBook Air without a fan is constantly overheating? ...

Comment: I’ve loved the original MacBook “one” with no blower. Did solid work on it and my M2 Air is the best Mac I’ve owned. Have you had Apple run diagnostics on yours @Adler we’re seeing them to be well behaved at work and more reliable than the ones with blowers TBH.

Comment: @Adler - some additional background on updated thermal pressure / thermal state change APIs: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/RespondToThermalStateChanges.html